# Convert ifstream input to template type

Tags: c++

I have a template class of type T. How would I go about converting values from a ifstream to said type? Is there any special cast?

I can't use static_cast or stod() for example.

I have to read in the value as a string so that I later can seperate the numbers from the letters. Therefore I can't use the >> operator.

If I use stream >> T. And T is a double. A string would cause an error, if I catch this error, is there a way to see the string that caused the error?

Comment: How about overloading the global `>>` operator for  `YourClass<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about converting values from a ifstream to said type? Is there any special cast?

There is no special cast.

If the file contains objects of type `T` that could be read from the file using `operator>>`, you could use:

```
T t;
stream >> t;
```

If the file contains objects of type `T` in binary format, you could read the objects of the type from the file using:

```
T t;
stream.read(static_cast<char*>(&t), sizeof(T));
```

Comment: stream >> t does work indeed. But I have to read it in as a string so that I can get all the values from the file. I have to seperate the values in the file in to two different files, one containing letters and one numbers.

Comment: You can read it into a string and then use a `std::istringstream` to read it into the `T`

Comment: @Lithicas, that's quite a bit different than the question in your post.